# How to implement Server-Side Datatables using CodeIgniter and Eloquent ORM

Tags: codeigniter, datatable, eloquent, illuminate-container

I have implemented Eloquent ORM using CodeIgniter and been able to fetch records from the database.
Need some help with implementing Server-side datatables using the above.
http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

Tried using this:
`$data = User::all()->toJson();`

Gets data in JSON but doesnt work as it needs more data for datatable like the number of records and number of times table is drawn etc.

I am really stuck out and this small fix would help me a lot.

Comment: Ariful Haque. I get that edit. But it doesnt solve the issue. The Line User::all() gets all data from the database but how should I get it to Server-Side datatable. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After various efforts instead of fetching data using ORM used Ignited Datatables library and pushed data to datatables. For now helped me. But would surely find some alternative by using the illuminate database.